# SSL handshake keeps failing when trying to read in .asp extension in URL

Tags: java, ssl, https, sslhandshakeexception

```
 try {
            System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2");

            URL url = new URL("https://clerkweb.summitoh.net/Welcome.asp");

            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(stream);

            String line = buff.readLine();

            while (line != null ){
                line = buff.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//The Error I get

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:994)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
    at main.main(main.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    ... 9 more
```

Tried each TLS protocol version. Not sure if it has to do with the fact it is a .asp app I'm reading in but figured it doesn't matter cause it should just be posting html to the page anyways. Kind of confused on this one. Thank you for any help or info.

Comment: [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=clerkweb.summitoh.net) says the website is only accepting TLS 1.0 with a very poor set of cipher suites (one only). Check your Java version if it allows this cipher suite (have a look at the JSSE Reference Guide of the version you're running)

Comment: Defiantly is what is is. JDK 6 doesn't even support this cipher. If any JDK at all.

Comment: Re-checked, SSLLabs says JDK 6/7/8 can perform the handshake. Try enabling the legacy algorithms (jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms system property as given in the Reference Guide)

Comment: Wait nvm. It was there I just have to try and enable it

Comment: Still not working even after I remove it from legacy algorithms :(

Comment: There's no way to "Enable it" or anything in the docs from what I am reading

Comment: I can download your URL without problem with a Java client. Enable the debugging options with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` . Maybe you're not trusting the certificate authority ?